# How to configure JsonOptions for SignalR in .NET Core 2.2?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-signalr

I want to add the `StringEnumConverter` to my serializer settings for SignalR but I can't seem to find a way how to do this.

Right now i added the attribute on my transfer object that does the trick but it would be much nicer to define this globally like you can with Mvc

```
services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(options =>
{
    options.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new StringEnumConverter(true));
});
```

But then for SignalR.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be achieved by chaining a call to `AddJsonProtocol` on to `AddSignalR` in `ConfigureServices`. Here's an example:

```
services.AddSignalR()
    .AddJsonProtocol(options =>
    {
        options.PayloadSerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new StringEnumConverter(true));
    });
```

Reference: [JSON/MessagePack serialization options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/configuration?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=dotnet#jsonmessagepack-serialization-options)

Comment: Thanks heaps! Just saved my day! This fixed the exception when SignalR is sending details to client: "Serialization and deserialization of 'System.DateOnly' instances are not supported"

Comment: .NET 6 uses "PayloadSerializerOptions" instead of "PayloadSerializerSettings". Just a reminder for anyone using newer versions

Comment: Any idea how I could set the options per Hub instead of globally?